# Create a native pipe compatible table() function

Tags: r, function, dplyr, pipe, pivot-table

I am looking to develop a **`tab(x, y)`** function or `tab(x, y, d)` (where d = data.frame) to replace this command:

```r
d <- mtcars
d |> dplyr::select(cyl, vs) |> table()
```

I try:

```r
d <- mtcars
tab <- function (x, y) {
  result <- table(x, y)
  result
}
```

Without pipe, it's ok:

```r
tab(d$cyl, d$vs)
```

With native pipe it doesn't work:

```r
d |> tab(cyl, vs)
```

But it works with exposition pipe (`%$%`) from the magrittr package

```r
d %$% tab(cyl, vs)
```

How to adapt the function to work with the native pipe operator (`|>`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tab <- function(d, x, y){
  eval(substitute(table(d$x, d$y)))
}

mtcars |> tab(cyl, vs)
   
     0  1
  4  1 10
  6  3  4
  8 14  0
```

Answer (score 1):

It can work with the native pipe, one way is to create an anonymous function like:

`(\(df){...})()`

So you can have something like

```
d |> (\(df){
  
  with(df, tab(cyl, vs))
})()
```

```
   y
x    0  1
  4  1 10
  6  3  4
  8 14  0
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `tabyl` from `janitor`

```
library(janitor)
d |> 
   tabyl(cyl, vs)
```

-output

```
 cyl  0  1
   4  1 10
   6  3  4
   8 14  0
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `dplyr` framework you can embrace function arguments:

```r
tab <- function(d, x, y) {
    select(d, {{x}}, {{y}}) |>
        table()
}

mtcars |> tab(cyl, vs)
##>    vs
##> cyl  0  1
##>   4  1 10
##>   6  3  4
##>   8 14  0
```