# Can Dplyr pipe a data frame into the table(function)?

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe, tidyr

I have a data frame of the following type:

```
Date        X1 ....
2010-01-01  4
2010-01-02  5
2010-01-27  4
2012-03-10  2
...
```

So I am using the `table()` function to see the frequency of sampling each day/month. That means that I'm not looking at the values of each sampling, only it there is one that day. The thing is, I have generated an additional column called "season" using the "hydroTSM" package. So my idea is to use the following code:

```
df %>%
  filter(date >= "2010-01-01") %>%
  filter(date <= "2010-12-30") %>%
  table(.$season)
```

But it gives me error.

```
Error in xtrm.data.frame(x) :cannot xtfrm data frames.
```

However if I save it as a "date" variable and then do "`table(date$season)`" I get what I wanted.

```
 data <-  df %>%
      filter(date >= "2010-01-01") %>%
      filter(date <= "2010-12-30") %>%
      as.data.frame(df$date, df$season)

table(data$season)
```

Is it possible to do this with pipes?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75304716/create-a-native-pipe-compatible-table-function/75305173#75305173

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I would also use the exposition pipe, another option would be to use  `with`.

```r
library(magrittr)
mtcars %>% 
  with(table(cyl, gear))
```

The thing to understand is that `%>%` places the left hand side into the corresponding position of the right hand side (typically in the first slot).

Thus, `mtcars %>% table(.$cyl)` translates to `table(mtcars, .$cyl)` as you can easily verify:

```r
trace(table, quote(print(list(...))))

# Tracing table(., .$cyl) on entry 
# [[1]]
#                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
# Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
# Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
# Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
# Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
# Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
# Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
# Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
# Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
# Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
# Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
# Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
# Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
# Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
# Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
# Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
# Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
# AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
# Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
# Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
# Fiat X1-9           27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
# Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
# Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
# Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
# Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
# Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
# Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
# 
# [[2]]
#  [1] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 8 6 8 4
# 
# Error in xtfrm.data.frame(x) : 
#   (converted from warning) cannot xtfrm data frames
```

That is, technically the term `.$cyl` is understood and properly evaluated, but `tidyverse` does not recognize it as it does with the single dot (i.e. use the LHS at this position and **not** in the first:

```r
f <- function(a, b) print(list(a = a, b = b))

2 %>% f("a")
# $a
# [1] 2

# $b
# [1] "a"

# 2 %>% f("a", .)
# $a
# [1] "a"

# $b
# [1] 2
```

In the second case, tidyverse recognize the presence of `.` and thus does not add it again as the first argument.

---

### Update

The IMHO cleanest approach is to surround the RHS with curly braces like this, which overrides the default behavior of placing the dot in the first slot:

```r
mtcars %>% 
  { table(.$cyl, .$gear) }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the exposition pipe [`%$%`](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/exposition.html) to use the columns as argument without a `data` argument.

```r
library(magrittr)
mtcars %$% 
  table(cyl, gear)

#    gear
# cyl  3  4  5
#   4  1  8  2
#   6  2  4  1
#   8 12  0  2
```

Answer (score 0):

When dot is nested, lhs is still placed first. This can be avoided with {}.
See [What are the differences and use cases of the five Magrittr Pipes %>%, %<>%, %$%, %!>% and %T>%?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76326742) for additional alternatives.

```
library(magrittr)
mtcars %>% 
  {table(.$cyl)}
#
# 4  6  8 
#11  7 14
```